# The elements in the "SELECT LIST" list must be separated using commas

Tags: abap

I want to do the following select, but it returned an error that I don't know what to do.

> The elements in the "SELECT LIST" list must be separated using commas.

My version is NW 7.4. Could anyone help me ?

```
TYPES : BEGIN OF ty_meal,
          carrid     TYPE smeal-carrid,
          mealnumber TYPE smeal-mealnumber,
          text       TYPE smealt-text,
        END OF ty_meal,
        ty_meal_s TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_meal WITH EMPTY KEY.
DATA meals TYPE ty_meal_s.

SELECT smeal~carrid smeal~mealnumber smealt~text
  INTO TABLE meals
  FROM smeal
    LEFT JOIN smealt 
        ON smealt~carrid = smeal~carrid
        AND smealt~mealnumber = smeal~mealnumber
  WHERE smealt~sprache EQ 'E'.
```

Comment: This doesn't work. When I change the 'left join' by 'inner join' it works. Do you know why ?

Comment: : Cloud you please describe (1) what you expect, (2) in how far the actual result differs from your expections and (3) modify your code, such that it is a functional, minimal working example including definitions for all the host variables you used? By the way: The column `MANDT` is automatically compared when joining the client dependet tables.

Comment: You can only use one outer join in a ´SELECT´ statement at the same time. ´LEFT JOIN´ is an outer join, thus you can only use it once

Comment: I edited the question so that it is a minimal reproducible example

Comment: The (unclear) message is due to the fact that your ABAP SQL code has a feature which can only works with the strict mode (requires commas, @ in front of ABAP variables, and so on). The concerned feature is the filtering on a column of a "left join" table (I think it's since [7.40 SP05](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abennews-740_sp05-open_sql.htm), only in strict mode).

Comment: Stop writing `EQ`. It is not Fortran or Cobol anymore. Use `=`.

Comment: @Legxis, I tried to used one left join and didn't work.

Comment: @Jagger Offtopic: I prefer `eq` over `=` in ABAP to clearly distinguish between assignments and comparisons. If ABAP had a `==` I'd use that of course.

Comment: What is your ABAP version?

Comment: @SandraRossi, NW 7.4

Comment: @konstantin Sorry but this is so 1960. You can clearly see comparisons in ABAP because they begin with `IF` and there is absolutely no way to do an assignment after an `IF` in ABAP.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I've solved my problem. It's the mandt, I was trying to do the select with the mandt

```
 `ON ( aufk~mandt EQ afih~mandt   AND aufk~aufnr EQ afih~aufnr )`
```

but itns't necessary. I've changed to

```
  `ON (aufk~aufnr EQ afih~aufnr )`
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to separate the columns you `SELECT` with commas, like this

```sql
SELECT smeal~carrid, smeal~mealnumber, smealt~text
  INTO TABLE @meals
  FROM smeal
    LEFT JOIN smealt 
        ON smealt~carrid = smeal~carrid
        AND smealt~mealnumber = smeal~mealnumber
  WHERE smealt~sprache EQ 'E'.
```

Answer (score 4):

Before release 7.40 SP05, you cannot use the `WHERE` clause to filter on a column of a "right" table in a LEFT OUTER JOIN ([ABAP 7.31 doc](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_731_index_htm/7.31/en-US/index.htm?url=abapselect_join.htm): "In outer joins, all comparisons that contain columns from the database table or view dbtab_right on the right side [...] These columns are not allowed as operands in the WHERE condition of the same SELECT statement.")

This restriction was logical because if one line is only in the left table, all the columns of the right table are considered "null", so, if there's a selection on a column of the right table, the line will not be selected (except if `IS NULL` is used).

The right way is to define the condition in the `ON`:

```
  SELECT smeal~carrid smeal~mealnumber smealt~text
    INTO TABLE meals
    FROM smeal
      LEFT JOIN smealt
          ON smealt~carrid = smeal~carrid
          AND smealt~mealnumber = smeal~mealnumber
          AND smealt~sprache EQ 'E'.                 " <==== move it from WHERE to ON
```

Comment: look how my select is right now but doesn't work yet.

Comment: @AlisonVieira Stack Overflow is a forum with rules. One of them is to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which is currently not the case: you must not copy your code but recreate one for Stack Overflow, as explained clearly in the link. Please try with the reproducible code I proposed and you can see it solves your question (I also tried with your code, spent time to write the missing code (!!), and it worked). NB: I will have to revert your question revision (or another power user will do it).